# Editors for different parts of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, roles

I'm preparing my page (not published yet) and need Your help. I didn't find any answer in forums about roles and capabilities. Have you heard about plugin or an other solution, that allows editor to publish only in his category/page. 
I have 10 departments, in each of them 1 author and 1 editor. I need to ensure that editor from department 1 can not publish for department 2.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to [install WordPress as a multi-site network](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/importer) and give each department their own site.  You can do this based on sudomains (`department-1.mysite.com`, `department-2.mysite.com`, etc.) or as subfolders (`mysite.com/department-1`, `mysite-.com/department-2`, etc.).

Users can have different roles across each site in the network.  You, as the super administrator, would have full access to everything.  If you have an author who's only supposed to be an author on one department's site, you can limit them that way.  You can also grant a user permission to be an author on one site, an editor on another, and merely a subscriber on another.  It's a very flexible system.

This is the easiest way to separate authors into specific "departments" within WordPress ... and the biggest advantage is that *you don't need a plug-in to make it work!*